# Adding to set() if part of tuple not exists

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I would like to use something similar to the add() function to add tuples to a set. However, I want them not to be added if a part of that tuple already exists in the set.

For example:

```
mySet = set()
myList = [['A','B',1],['B','C',2],['C','D',3],['A','B',2]]

for i in myList:
    mySet.add(((i[0],i[1]),i[2]))
```

This gives me a result as:

```
mySet = (('A', 'B'), 1), (('A', 'B'), 2), (('B', 'C'), 2), (('C', 'D'), 3)
```

But I would like the ('A','B')-combination to only appear once (the first time it is added), so that my result is:

```
mySet = {(('A', 'B'), 1), (('B', 'C'), 2), (('C', 'D'), 3)}
```

Comment: A set alone can't help you much there. Either you write a custom class for your tuples with a custom hash method that only considers the first two items; or you use a dict to store your tuples and use just the first two items as keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the data to a dictionary first.

```
my_list = [['A','B',1],['B','C',2],['C','D',3],['A','B',2]]
my_dict = {tuple([*x[:2]]):x[2] for x in reversed(my_list)}
# alternative for the previous line: my_dict = {(x, y): z for x, y, z in reversed(my_list)}
print(my_dict)  # debug output
my_set = {*my_dict.items()}  # or: my_set = set(my_dict.items())
print(my_set)
```

Output for `my_dict` is `{('A', 'B'): 1, ('C', 'D'): 3, ('B', 'C'): 2}`.

The final set is `{(('A', 'B'), 1), (('B', 'C'), 2), (('C', 'D'), 3)}`.

According to your wanted output you want the first element from the list that matches the criteria. So we have to loop over the list backwards with `reversed`. Otherwise a later value would overwrite the first matching entry.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a dictionary in that case?

```
d = {}
for i,j,k in myList:
    if (i,j) not in d:
        d[(i,j)] = k
mySet = set(d.items())
```

As @Matthias suggests, `reversed` makes it even better:

```
mySet = set({(i,j): k for i,j,k in reversed(myList)}.items())
```

Output:

```
{(('A', 'B'), 1), (('B', 'C'), 2), (('C', 'D'), 3)}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Now drop in a `reversed` for `myList` in your code and you get the first matching element from the list.